# IBKR Python File - Close All Existing Positions before Opening a New Position

Tags: python, interactive-brokers

Please can someone assist.

I have a Python file which automatically places a Futures Option trade (based on an incoming webhook from TradingView). However, before I place the new trade, I want to cancel all existing trades in IBKR. Below is the correct code which places an initial entry:

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
import subprocess
import json
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.order import Order
import threading
import time

def run_loop():
    app.run()

class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.nextorderId = None

    def nextValidId(self, orderId: int):
        super().nextValidId(orderId)
        self.nextorderId = orderId
        print('The next valid order id is: ', self.nextorderId)

    def orderStatus(self, orderId, status, filled, remaining, avgFullPrice, permId, parentId, lastFillPrice, clientId,
                    whyHeld, mktCapPrice):
        print('orderStatus - orderid:', orderId, 'status:', status, 'filled', filled, 'remaining', remaining,
              'lastFillPrice', lastFillPrice)

    def openOrder(self, orderId, contract, order, orderState):
        print('openOrder id:', orderId, contract.symbol, contract.secType, '@', contract.exchange, ':', order.action,
              order.orderType, order.totalQuantity, orderState.status)

    def execDetails(self, reqId, contract, execution):
        print('Order Executed: ', reqId, contract.symbol, contract.secType, contract.currency, execution.execId,
              execution.orderId, execution.shares, execution.lastLiquidity)



# Listen for incoming webhook data
url = "https://api.pipedream.com/sources/dc_2Eu7X4x/sse"
auth_header = "Authorization: Bearer 360d90f4549def76cc1e370e71832b67"
curl_cmd = ["curl", "-s", "-N", "-H", auth_header, url]
proc = subprocess.Popen(curl_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in proc.stdout:
    # Ignore any SSE data that isn't JSON-formatted
    if line.startswith(b"data: {"):
        # Strip the "data: " prefix from the line and parse the JSON-formatted data
        event_data = json.loads(line[6:])
        # Process the event data as needed
        data = event_data
        body = data['event']['body']
        symbol_fields = body.split(',')
        print(symbol_fields[0])
        print(symbol_fields[1])
        print(symbol_fields[2])
        print(symbol_fields[3])
        print(symbol_fields[4])
        print(symbol_fields[5])
        print(symbol_fields[6])

        def options_order(symbol):
            contract = Contract()
            contract.symbol = symbol_fields[0]
            contract.secType = symbol_fields[1]
            contract.exchange = symbol_fields[2]
            contract.currency = symbol_fields[3]
            contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = symbol_fields[4]
            contract.strike = symbol_fields[5]
            contract.right = symbol_fields[6]
            contract.multiplier = symbol_fields[7]
            return contract

        app = IBapi()
        app.connect('127.0.0.1', 4002, 123)

        app.nextorderId = None

        # Start the socket in a thread
        api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
        api_thread.start()

        # Check if the API is connected via orderid
        while True:
            if isinstance(app.nextorderId, int):
                print('connected')
                break
            else:
                print('waiting for connection')
                time.sleep(1)

        # Create order object
        contract = options_order(symbol_fields)
        order = Order()
        order.action = 'BUY'
        order.totalQuantity = 1
        order.orderType = 'MKT'
        order.eTradeOnly = ''
        order.firmQuoteOnly = ''

        # Place order
        app.placeOrder(app.nextorderId, options_order('TSLA'), order)
        # app.nextorderId += 1

        time.sleep(3)

        # Cancel order
        #print('cancelling order')
        #app.cancelOrder(app.nextorderId)

        time.sleep(3)
        app.disconnect()
```

HOWEVER, if I add (replace the following):

```
def position(self, account, contract, position, avgCost):
    print('Position:', account, contract.symbol, position, avgCost)
    # Place a market order to close the position
    order = Order()
    order.action = 'SELL' if position > 0 else 'BUY'
    order.orderType = 'MKT'
    order.totalQuantity = abs(position)
    self.placeOrder(self.nextorderId, contract, order)
    self.nextorderId += 1

def __init__(self):
    EClient.__init__(self, self)
    self.nextorderId = 1
def options_order(self, symbol_fields):
    contract = Contract()
    contract.symbol = symbol_fields[0]
    contract.secType = symbol_fields[1]
    contract.exchange = symbol_fields[2]
    contract.currency = symbol_fields[3]
    contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = symbol_fields[4]
    contract.strike = symbol_fields[5]
    contract.right = symbol_fields[6]
    contract.multiplier = symbol_fields[7]
    return contract

while True:
    if isinstance(app.nextorderId, int):
        print('connected')
        # Request open positions
        app.reqPositions()
        time.sleep(2)
        # Place order
        contract = app.options_order(symbol_fields)
        order = Order()
        order.action = 'BUY'
        order.totalQuantity = 1
        order.orderType = 'MKT'
        order.eTradeOnly = ''
        order.firmQuoteOnly = ''
        app.placeOrder(app.nextorderId, contract, order)
        app.nextorderId += 1
        break
    else:
        print('waiting for connection')
        time.sleep(1)
```

I then receive errors and the script no longer works. I have tried everything but to no avail.
Would greatly appreciate the help

Thank You
Wes

Comment: Any errors logs to provide ?

Comment: Please add the full traceback of the received error to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I finally came right...

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
import subprocess
import json
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.order import Order
import threading
import time
import csv

def run_loop():
    app.run()

class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.nextorderId = None

    def nextValidId(self, orderId: int):
        super().nextValidId(orderId)
        self.nextorderId = orderId
        print('The next valid order id is: ', self.nextorderId)

    def orderStatus(self, orderId, status, filled, remaining, avgFullPrice, permId, parentId, lastFillPrice, clientId,
                    whyHeld, mktCapPrice):
        print('orderStatus - orderid:', orderId, 'status:', status, 'filled', filled, 'remaining', remaining,
              'lastFillPrice', lastFillPrice)

    def openOrder(self, orderId, contract, order, orderState):
        print('openOrder id:', orderId, contract.symbol, contract.secType, '@', contract.exchange, ':', order.action,
              order.orderType, order.totalQuantity, orderState.status)

    def execDetails(self, reqId, contract, execution):
        print('Order Executed: ', reqId, contract.symbol, contract.secType, contract.currency, execution.execId,
              execution.orderId, execution.shares, execution.lastLiquidity)

# Create an instance of the IBapi class
app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 4002, 123)
app.nextorderId = None

# Start the socket in a thread
api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start()

# Check if the API is connected via orderid
while True:
    if isinstance(app.nextorderId, int):
        print('connected')
        break
    else:
        print('waiting for connection')
        time.sleep(1)

# Listen for incoming webhook data
while True:
    url = "https://api.pipedream.com/sources/dc_2Eu7X4x/sse"
    auth_header = "Authorization: Bearer 360d90f4549def76cc1e370e71832b67"
    curl_cmd = ["curl", "-s", "-N", "-H", auth_header, url]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(curl_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in proc.stdout:
    # Ignore any SSE data that isn't JSON-formatted
     if line.startswith(b"data: {"):
        # Strip the "data: " prefix from the line and parse the JSON-formatted data
        event_data = json.loads(line[6:])
        # Process the event data as needed
        data = event_data
        body = data['event']['body']
        symbol_fields = body.split(',')

        # Open the CSV file in "append" mode
        with open('filename.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
            # Create a CSV writer object
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            # Write a new row to the CSV file
            row = [symbol_fields[0],
                   symbol_fields[1],
                   symbol_fields[2],
                   symbol_fields[3],
                   symbol_fields[4],
                   symbol_fields[5],
                   symbol_fields[6],
                   symbol_fields[7]]
            writer.writerow(row)

        with open('filename.csv', 'r') as file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
            data = list(csv_reader)

        second_to_last_row = data[-2]
        if symbol_fields[6] == second_to_last_row[6]:
            continue
        else:
            def options_order_1(symbol):
                # Create SELL Contract Object
                contract_1 = Contract()
                contract_1.symbol = second_to_last_row[0]
                contract_1.secType = second_to_last_row[1]
                contract_1.exchange = second_to_last_row[2]
                contract_1.currency = second_to_last_row[3]
                contract_1.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = second_to_last_row[4]
                contract_1.strike = second_to_last_row[5]
                contract_1.right = second_to_last_row[6]
                contract_1.multiplier = second_to_last_row[7]
                return contract_1

            # Define the BUY Contract and Order Objects
            def options_order_2(symbol):
                # Create BUY Contract Object
                contract_2 = Contract()
                contract_2.symbol = symbol_fields[0]
                contract_2.secType = symbol_fields[1]
                contract_2.exchange = symbol_fields[2]
                contract_2.currency = symbol_fields[3]
                contract_2.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = symbol_fields[4]
                contract_2.strike = symbol_fields[5]
                contract_2.right = symbol_fields[6]
                contract_2.multiplier = symbol_fields[7]
                return contract_2

            # Create SELL Order Object
            contract_1 = options_order_1(second_to_last_row[0])
            order_1 = Order()
            order_1.action = 'SELL'
            order_1.totalQuantity = 1
            order_1.orderType = 'MKT'
            order_1.eTradeOnly = ''
            order_1.firmQuoteOnly = ''
            # Place the SELL Order
            app.placeOrder(app.nextorderId, contract_1, order_1)

            # Wait for the first order to be filled before placing the second order
            time.sleep(3)

            # Place BUY order
             # Create BUY Order Object
            contract_2 = options_order_2(symbol_fields[0])
            order_2 = Order()
            order_2.action = 'BUY'
            order_2.totalQuantity = 1
            order_2.orderType = 'MKT'
            order_2.eTradeOnly = ''
            order_2.firmQuoteOnly = ''
            # Place the BUY Order
            app.nextorderId += 1
            app.placeOrder(app.nextorderId, contract_2, order_2)
            app.nextorderId += 1
        time.sleep(3)
```